# EXTRACT vs CAST in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This question is mostly for an "Optimizing Code" kind of purpose.

So, in SQL, specifically Google BigQuery, there are 2 ways to transform a timestamp into a date or an hour. Using EXTRACT() or CAST().

There might be more ways to do so, but at least those are the ones I know of currently.

CAST() example:

```
SELECT
    CAST(tb.timestamp_field AS DATE) AS date_field, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    database.table tb
GROUP BY    
    CAST(tb.timestamp_field AS DATE)
```

EXTRACT() example:

```
SELECT
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM tb.timestamp_field) AS date_field, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    database.table tb
GROUP BY    
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM tb.timestamp_field)
```

Both methods work for what I'm trying to do, but I would like to know which one would be considered as a "best practice". Or maybe the whole questions could be silly, like asking which is better: "4+3-2" or "4-2+3". Which would be basically the same.

Comment: Not CAST nor EXTRACT! Use rather DATE(timestamp_field)

Answer (score 0):

my two cents -
**Cast** - preferable. Because lot of other big data tools uses similar format so if you have to ever migrate to another big data, you can migrate smoothly.
Also, in your SQL, cast is a direct operation so i think this can be faster. I tested this using one record and this sql took 0.011 sec.

```
SELECT  cast( TIMESTAMP "2018-12-25 05:30:00"  as date)
```

**Extract** - The SQL you are using is not official  - there is nothing like `EXTRACT(DATE from timestamp_col)`. Good way is to use what @
Mikhail Berlyant mentioned. but your sql is working - so i think internally, google big query engine is converting the timestamp to date and the removing time part. So its a two part operation and heavily depends on internal conversion. A little unreliable i think. Also, i think you can run both your query and check performance because perf depends on lot of factors like - environment, amount of data, optimized table, etc.
Also, below SQL took like 0.012 sec. (not a great perf indicator though)

```
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP "2018-12-25 05:30:00")
```

You can refer to below link for more on `EXTRACT` or `DATE` -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract